# Show graph in Umano sliding up panel

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio

I want to display the bar chart on the slide up panel. I am a complete begineer. Can anyone explain how to do it.
The codes are:

```
package com.digitaldesigner.adish.apptracker;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.pm.ActivityInfo;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.TabLayout;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;


import com.couchbase.lite.Database;
import com.couchbase.lite.DatabaseOptions;
import com.couchbase.lite.Document;
import com.couchbase.lite.Emitter;
import com.couchbase.lite.Manager;
import com.couchbase.lite.Mapper;
import com.couchbase.lite.android.AndroidContext;
import com.couchbase.lite.internal.InterfaceAudience;
import com.couchbase.lite.replicator.Replication;
import com.digitaldesigner.adish.apptracker.lockscreen.UnlockCountService;
import com.digitaldesigner.adish.apptracker.usagetracker.appUsage.PagerAdapter;
import com.digitaldesigner.adish.apptracker.usagetracker.barchart.BarChartView;
import com.sothree.slidinguppanel.SlidingUpPanelLayout;

import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.GregorianCalendar;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.UUID;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements Replication.ChangeListener {

    public static String TAG = "GrocerySync";
    public static int flag=0;
    public static int unlock=0;

    public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "sync_gateway";
    public static final String designDocName = "grocery-local";
    public static final String byDateViewName = "byDate";

    public static final String SYNC_URL = "http://172.16.143.150:4985/sync_gateway";

    protected static Manager manager;
    public static Database database;

    SlidingUpPanelLayout slidingUpPanel, slidingUpPanel1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        SharedPreferences preferences=getSharedPreferences("anyname", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor=preferences.edit();
        editor.putInt("unlock",unlock);
        editor.commit();

       if(preferences.getBoolean("firstTime", false)){
              editor.putLong("savedTime",System.currentTimeMillis());
            editor.commit();
           }






        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        slidingUpPanel = (SlidingUpPanelLayout) findViewById(R.id.sliding_layout);

         slidingUpPanel1 = (SlidingUpPanelLayout) findViewById(R.id.main_content);






        this.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tab_layout);
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Detailed View"));
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Pie-Chart View"));
        tabLayout.setTabGravity(TabLayout.GRAVITY_FILL);
        Intent myIntent = new Intent(this,UnlockCountService.class);
        this.startService(myIntent);
        final ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        final PagerAdapter adapter = new PagerAdapter
                (getSupportFragmentManager(), tabLayout.getTabCount());
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
        viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(tabLayout));
        tabLayout.setOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
                viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());

            }

            @Override
            public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            }
        });
        try {
            startCBLite();
        } catch (Exception e) {

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error Initializing CBLIte, see logs for details", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            com.couchbase.lite.util.Log.e("TAG", "Error initializing CBLite", e);
        }
    }
    protected void onDestroy() {
        if(manager != null) {
            manager.close();
        }
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    public void startCBLite() throws Exception {

        manager = new Manager(new AndroidContext(getApplicationContext()), Manager.DEFAULT_OPTIONS);
        DatabaseOptions options = new DatabaseOptions();
        options.setCreate(true);
        database = manager.openDatabase(DATABASE_NAME, options);
        com.couchbase.lite.View viewItemsByDate = database.getView(String.format("%s/%s", designDocName, byDateViewName));
        viewItemsByDate.setMap(new Mapper() {
            @Override
            public void map(Map<String, Object> document, Emitter emitter) {
                Object createdAt = document.get("created_at");
                if (createdAt != null) {
                    emitter.emit(createdAt.toString(), null);
                }
            }
        }, "1.0");
        startSync();
    }

    public  void startSync() {
        URL syncUrl;
        try {
            syncUrl = new URL(SYNC_URL);
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }

        Replication pullReplication = database.createPullReplication(syncUrl);
        pullReplication.setContinuous(true);

        Replication pushReplication = database.createPushReplication(syncUrl);
        pushReplication.setContinuous(true);

        pullReplication.start();
        pushReplication.start();

        pullReplication.addChangeListener(this);
        pushReplication.addChangeListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    public void changed(Replication.ChangeEvent event) {


    }

}
```

The code for the bar chart:

```
package com.digitaldesigner.adish.apptracker.usagetracker.barchart;



import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import com.couchbase.lite.CouchbaseLiteException;
import com.couchbase.lite.Document;
import com.couchbase.lite.replicator.Replication;
import com.github.mikephil.charting.charts.PieChart;
import com.github.mikephil.charting.data.PieData;
import com.github.mikephil.charting.data.PieDataSet;
import com.github.mikephil.charting.data.PieEntry;

//import com.github.mikephil.charting.charts.BarChart;

import com.digitaldesigner.adish.apptracker.R;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;


import static com.digitaldesigner.adish.apptracker.MainActivity.database;
import static com.digitaldesigner.adish.apptracker.MainActivity.flag;

public class BarChartView extends Fragment implements Replication.ChangeListener {
    public static int i = 0;
    public static String TAG = "GrocerySync";
    public static ArrayList<String> ydata = new ArrayList<String>();
    public static ArrayList<Float> xdata = new ArrayList<Float>();
    public static ArrayList<String> myDocId = new ArrayList<String>();
    public static ArrayList<Float> cpyf = new ArrayList<Float>();
    public static PieChart pieChart;

    @Override
    public void onStop() {super.onStop();}

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_bar_chart, container, false);
    }
    @Override
    public void onPause() {super.onPause();}

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View rootView, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        pieChart = (PieChart) rootView.findViewById(R.id.idPieChart);

        pieChart.setRotationEnabled(true);
        pieChart.setHoleRadius(55f);
        pieChart.setEntryLabelColor(Color.BLACK);
        pieChart.setTransparentCircleAlpha(0);
        pieChart.setCenterText("APP USAGE");
        pieChart.setCenterTextSize(20);
    }
    public static void addDataSet() {
        float others = 0; int flag2=0;
        ArrayList<PieEntry> xEntrys = new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayList<String> yEntrys = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < xdata.size(); i++) {
            if (xdata.get(i) < 5.0) {
                others += xdata.get(i);
                xdata.remove(i);
                ydata.remove(i);
            }
        }
        Log.e("test", "size" + xdata.size());
        for (int i = 0; i < ydata.size(); i++) {
            String value;
            value = ydata.get(i);
            for (int j = i + 1; j < ydata.size(); j++) {
                if (value.equals(ydata.get(j))) {
                    ydata.remove(j);
                    xdata.remove(j);
                }
            }
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < xdata.size(); i++) {
            Log.e("test", "percentage" + xdata.get(i));
            Log.e("test", "application name" + ydata.get(i));
            String str = ydata.get(i);
            float x = xdata.get(i);
            if(flag==0) {
                myDocId.add(createDocument(xdata.get(i), ydata.get(i)));
                flag++;
            }
            else
            {
                Log.e("updation","updation");
                for(int j=0;j<myDocId.size();j++) {
                    Document doc = database.getDocument(myDocId.get(j));
                    // We can directly access properties from the document object:
                    String percent=(String)doc.getProperty("percent");
                    String owner = (String) doc.getProperty("Applicationn name");
                    Log.e("String","String obtained"+owner);
                    if(owner.equals(ydata.get(i))){
                        flag2=1;
                        x=x+100;
                        String xs=x+"%";
                        Log.e("for checking percent 1"+xs,"percent 2"+percent);
                        if(!(percent.equals(x+"%")))
                        {
                            Document doc1 = database.getDocument(myDocId.get(j));
                            Map<String, Object> properties1 = new HashMap<String, Object>();
                            properties1.putAll(doc1.getProperties());
                            properties1.put("percent", x + "%");
                            properties1.put("Applicationn name", str);
                            try {
                                doc.putProperties(properties1);
                            } catch (CouchbaseLiteException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                        else{
                            continue;
                        }
                    }
                }
                if(flag2==0){
                    Log.e("not matching excitsing","adding"+ydata.get(i));
                    myDocId.add(createDocument(xdata.get(i), ydata.get(i)));

                }
                flag2=0;

            }
            Log.e("test", "index" + i);
            xEntrys.add(new PieEntry(xdata.get(i), ydata.get(i)));


        }

        for (int i = 0; i < ydata.size(); i++) {
            yEntrys.add(ydata.get(i));

        }

        PieDataSet pieDataSet = new PieDataSet(xEntrys, " ");
        pieDataSet.setSliceSpace(4);
        pieDataSet.setValueTextSize(10);

        ArrayList<Integer> colors = new ArrayList<>();
        colors.add(Color.GREEN);
        colors.add(Color.RED);
        colors.add(Color.CYAN);
        colors.add(Color.BLUE);
        colors.add(Color.MAGENTA);
        colors.add(Color.YELLOW);
        colors.add(Color.rgb(255,127,80));


        pieDataSet.setColors(colors);
        PieData pieData = new PieData(pieDataSet);
        pieChart.setData(pieData);
        pieChart.invalidate();
    }


    @Override
    public void changed(Replication.ChangeEvent event) {

        Replication replication = event.getSource();
        com.couchbase.lite.util.Log.d(TAG, "Replication : " + replication + " changed.");
        if (!replication.isRunning()) {
            String msg = String.format("Replicator %s not running", replication);
            com.couchbase.lite.util.Log.d(TAG, msg);

        } else {
            int processed = replication.getCompletedChangesCount();
            int total = replication.getChangesCount();
            String msg = String.format("Replicator processed %d / %d", processed, total);
            com.couchbase.lite.util.Log.d(TAG, msg);
        }
    }
    private static String createDocument(float x, String s) {
        Log.e("test", "entered document creation");
        Document document = database.createDocument();
        String documentId = document.getId();
        Log.e("oru valya test", "document id:" + document.getId());
        Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        map.put("percent", x + "%");
        map.put("Applicationn name", s);
        try {
            // Save the properties to the document
            document.putProperties(map);
        } catch (CouchbaseLiteException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Error putting", e);
        }
        return documentId;

    }

}
```

XMl Layout of Main Activity:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <com.sothree.slidinguppanel.SlidingUpPanelLayout xmlns:sothree="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/sliding_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="bottom"
        sothree:umanoDragView="@+id/dragView"
        sothree:umanoOverlay="true"
        sothree:umanoPanelHeight="68dp"
        sothree:umanoShadowHeight="4dp"
        android:elevation="6dp">

        <!-- MAIN CONTENT -->
<RelativeLayout
android:id="@+id/main_layout"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">



<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:background="?android:attr/colorPrimary"
    android:elevation="6dp"
    android:minHeight="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
    tools:targetApi="lollipop" />

<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout

    android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"
    android:background="?android:attr/colorPrimary"
    android:elevation="6dp"
    android:minHeight="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
    tools:targetApi="lollipop" />

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />





</RelativeLayout>

        <!-- SLIDING LAYOUT -->



        <fragment android:name="com.digitaldesigner.adish.apptracker.usagetracker.barchart.BarChartView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/idPieChart"
            >
        </fragment>

    </com.sothree.slidinguppanel.SlidingUpPanelLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

XML Layout of BAR CHART:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <com.github.mikephil.charting.charts.PieChart
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/idPieChart"
        >

    </com.github.mikephil.charting.charts.PieChart>

</RelativeLayout>
```

I am a complete begineer. Initilly I was displaying the piechart in a seperate tab . Can anyone please help me?

Comment: What problem you are facing ?

Comment: I am trying to add the graph fragment, but  pie chart is not showing anything.